# Remove array element with YiiMongoDbSuite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I have some code that should be deleting a record from an embedded MongoDB document.

Here is the code:

```
    public function actionDeleteSaved()
    {
        $savedLink = $_POST['savedLink'];
        $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
        $current = SaveLink::model()->findByPk($userId);

        if(in_array($savedLink, $current->links))
        {
            array_slice($current->links, $savedLink);
            $current->save();
        }
    }
```

This is what is passing the data to the controllers action method:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
        'delete', 
        Yii::app()->createUrl("dashboard/index/deletesaved"),
        array( // ajax options
            'type' => 'POST',
            'context' => "js:this",
            'data' => array(
                'savedLink' => $savedLink
            )
        ),
        array( //html options
            'class'=>'deleteSaved'
        )
    );
```

This is what renderPartial looks like:

```
        $this->renderPartial('_deleteSaved', array('savedLink'=>$s));
```

What I want being posted is being posted correctly but I'm not sure if it's communicating with the Controller and passing the data through or if my code for removing the data from the database is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `array_slice` part. As [specified in php docs](http://www.php.net/array_slice) array slice does **not** modify array parameter.

Use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) instead (it modifies passed array param) and [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) to get key:

```
if(in_array($savedLink, $current->links))
{
        $key = array_search($savedLink, $current->links);
        array_splice($current->links, $key, 0);
        $current->save();
}
```

**NOTE**: If `$current->links` is embedded documents (objects) array, you might have to find `$key` and check if is in array some other way.

Comment: Hey, array_splice didn't work but this did:
            $savedLink = $_POST['savedLink'];
            $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
            $current = SaveLink::model()->findByPk($userId);

            if(key_exists($savedLink, $current->links))
            {   
                unset($current->links[$savedLink]);
                $current->save();
            }